# Wordpress - link to the wrong css

Tags: css, wordpress

I created a wordpress site using a temporary url temp.mysite.com
I moved this to the customer URL www.customer.com but and I edited the file wp-config using the new domain.

The problem is that the new website is uploading the css and jQuery from the temp.mysite.com and if I delete this "temporary" website (temp.mysite.com) the customer website doesn't upload the CSS anymore.

How can I link the css hosted in www.customer.com?

Answer (score 0):

You can link absolutely

```
href="/styles/file.css"
```

Or relatively, eg.

```
href="../styles/file.css"
```

Or using the domain name

```
href="example.com/styles/file.css"
```

Path to styles you have to change into your real path, of course (I don't know WP but U expect it will be somewhere in the main template).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Url on dashboard, or if you can't access it try changing on database

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This parameter is set correct. But it's still uploading the CSS from the other url

Comment: can you give me the site or check manually the "view page source" to find the path of css?
is this css generated from plugins or is within the template

Comment: Where I can see which file generate the CSS path? The site is this one http://www.hidalgoanimazione.it/

Comment: as seen here `view-source:http://www.hidalgoanimazione.it/` you have a lot of url resolved on old domain, are you sure you changed both url up. Do you use a standard wordpress theme or you create it modifying the .php files?

Comment: you can search on the header file, ex header.php to see the way the link are generated

Comment: It's likely that you haven't enqueued your CSS correctly using `wp_enqueue_styles()` or haven't hooked it correctly to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. [Read this guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/loading-css-into-wordpress-the-right-way--cms-20402) for more info.